# Growth rate of the Hausdorff measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

Let the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure for a Borel set $F \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be denoted as follows:

$$\mathcal{H}^s(F) := \lim_{\delta \to 0} \mathcal{H}^s_\delta(F) := \lim_{\delta \to 0} \inf \left\{ \sum_i |A_i|^s: \text{ $\{A_i\}_i$ is a $\delta$-cover of $F$ } \right\}, $$
where the infimum is taken over all the $\delta$-covers of $F$. Then the Hausdorff dimension of this set is defined as follows:

$$\dim_{H} F := \sup \{s>0; \> \mathcal{H}^s(F) = + \infty \} = \inf \{s>0 : \> \mathcal{H}^s(F) = 0 \}.$$

My question is as follows.

> Let us assume that $\dim_{H} F = \alpha$. Can we prove an upper-bound of the following form? (for a **fixed** $\delta >0$ and bounded $F$)
>   $$ \log \mathcal{H}^\alpha_\delta(F) \leq C (\alpha + c) \log \frac1{\delta},$$
>   for some $C,c > 0$.

I have the feeling that $c$ can be equal to $1$, but at this stage any $c$ should work for my purpose. On the other hand we can replace $\alpha$ with any $0<q < \alpha$ if it's going to be any easier. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me on this issue.

Comment: isn't this false whenever $\mathcal{H}^{\alpha}(F) = \infty$, since then $\mathcal{H}_\delta^\alpha(F) = \infty$ for each $\delta$?

Comment: I don't think so. $\mathcal{H}^\alpha_\delta$ increases as $\delta$ decreases. But it doesn't necessarily mean that it's infinite.

Comment: you're right. however, you can take $F = \mathbb{R}^1$, for example, which does satisfy $\mathcal{H}^1_\delta(F) = \infty$ for each $\delta$.

Comment: you are right, I should precise the question that $F$ is bounded.

Comment: are you sure you want $\delta$ to be fixed? It seems like you want a uniform bound which applies for all $\delta$, for fixed $F$.