# Upper bound on the exact Hausdorff measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

Let the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure for a Borel set $F \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be denoted as follows:

$$\mathcal{H}^s(F) := \lim_{\delta \to 0} \mathcal{H}^s_\delta(F) := \lim_{\delta \to 0} \inf \left\{ \sum_i |A_i|^s: \text{ $\{A_i\}_i$ is a $\delta$-cover of $F$ } \right\}, $$
where $|A_i|$ denotes the diameter of the set $A_i$ and the infimum is taken over all the $\delta$-covers of $F$.

Let us consider a *bounded* set $A$ with the property $0 <\mathcal{H}^s(A) < \infty$, for some $0<s<d$. I am wondering if we can obtain an upper bound of the following form:
$$\mathcal{H}^s(A) \leq C |A|^s. $$

I found a density estimate in Mattila's book, Theorem 6.2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxhaj.jpg). However, I couldn't figure out how to use it. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me on this issue.

PS: There is also a related question in this post: 
[Growth rate of the Hausdorff measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600606/growth-rate-of-the-hausdorff-measure)

Comment: By bounded you mean something like "bounded diameter"? Also, what do you mean by $|A|$, the diameter of $A$? There is also a $q$ in the exponent of $|A_i|$ that doesn't seem defined.

Comment: I think that, if by $|A|$ you mean the diameter, you can build a ball $B$ or radius $\sim |A|$ and containing $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections, now the question should be clearer. The problem of bounding with a ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is that $\mathcal{H}^s(B) = \infty$, since $s<d$. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Consider a curve of finite length in the unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$-- by zig-zagging or otherwise, the length (which equals $\mathcal{H}^1$) can be made arbitrarily large while the diameter remains bounded

Comment: We are given that $\mathcal{H}^s(A)$ is finite and positive (also $s$ doesn't need to be an integer). Your example is taking $s=1$ and the question already assumes that $\mathcal{H}^s(A)$ cannot be infinity.

Comment: My example has finite $\mathcal{H}^1$ (since it's a curve with finite length) -- I'm saying that you can find curves with arbitrarily high (but finite) $\mathcal{H}^1$ within the unit disk

Comment: I don't understand the conclusion. Then isn't $|A|^1$ just the length of $A$ in that case?

Comment: By $|A|^1$ you meant the diameter, right? the diameter is always bounded by $2$ since the curve lies in the unit disk.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the confusion, I'll think about it

Comment: yeah, the question is formulated in a way in which it is only nontrivial if the $C$ doesn't depend on the set $A$, since $A$. But in that case it is false, by the example of user125932. A valid modification of the question would be if for every $A$ with $0 < \mathcal{H}^s(A) < \infty$ there exists a constant $C_A$ such that $\mathcal{H}^s(A \cap B_r(a)) \leq C_A \, r^s$.